# Serial - DeviceOpen - Baudrate Error

Tags: bugs, input-devices

When trying:

```
ser = DeviceOpen["Serial", {"COM1", "BaudRate" -> 230400}]
```

I get:

```
SerialLink`SerialPortOpen::baudrate: Value of option BaudRate -> 230400 is not
110, 300, 600, 1200, 2400, 4800, 9600, 14400, 19200, 28800, 38400, 56000, 57600, 
115200, 128000, 256000.
```

So obviously the Std BR of 230400 is not supported, although the Help for `DeviceOpen` in the Serial-context explicitly says:

> Typical baud rate values include: 4800, 9600, 19200, 38400, 57600, 115200, 230400.

Unfortunately I need 230400 to connect to the external device.
Is there any way of setting a baudrate other than through `DeviceOpen`?

Comment: 1. The Mathematica source of SerialLink is readable and found in SystemFiles/Links/SerialLink.  Looking at it it is clear that the allowed baud rates are hard coded, and do not match what the documentation says (i.e. 230400 is not included).  This suggests a bug.  Please contact Wolfram and report it (i.e. that the docs mention 230400 but it's not supported).  2. Try modifying ``SerialLink`Private`$ValidBaudRates``.  You must run the `DeviceOpen` call first to trigger loading all the required bits.  Once done, modify that variable, add 230400 to it, and see if it works.  It might not, but try.

Comment: Thank you Szabolcs. I will report it as bug. I also tried - similar to what you suggested - modifying the actual SerialLink.m File and added 230400 to the list of valid baudrates. Then DeviceOpen gave no error, but the actually transmitted bytes are garbled in this case. I guess the underlying DLL can't get close enough to this baudrate...Too bad.

Comment: What happens when you use 256000 as baud rate?

Comment: This [discussion on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/arduino/comments/2l6nt1/has_anyone_interfaced_arduino_with_mathematica/) might be relevant

Answer (score 8):

If you are under Windows, it is possible to access the RS232 port via `` netLink` ``.

```
<< NETLink` 
InstallNET[]

ser = NETNew["System.IO.Ports.SerialPort", "COM1"]
ser @ Open[]
ser @ BaudRate = 230400
```

I don't have any device at 230400 Bauds. To try the port, I have made a shortcut between pin 2 and 3 of my connector (ie Transmitter linked to Receiver) and it works :

```
ser @ WriteLine["Hello"]

ser @ ReadLine[]
```

> "Hello"

To see how to use the object `ser` type :

```
NETTypeInfo[ser]
```

The main properties/methods are :

```
ser @ Open[]
ser @ Close[]
ser @ BaudRate
ser @ Parity
ser @ StopBits
ser @ ReadTimeout
ser @ DataBits
ser @ RtsEnable
ser @ CtsHolding
ser @ DsrHolding
ser @ DtrEnable
ser @ Handshake
ser @ IsOpen
ser @ PortName
```

Comment: Sascha: The sensor I am trying to interface to is a custom thing with only "standard" Baudrate capability so the 256k aren't possible.
Andre: Thank you - this is a very interesting approach. But what happens when this is supposed to work under Windows and Linux? I was hoping that using Mathematica could get me the cross-platform functionality here, but then this problem threw a wrench in it...

Comment: @swoo There is a package named SerialIO [here](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/5726/) that may be usefull (It's another solution that has nothing to do with netLink)

Comment: Thank you for that hint. Actually that's what I tried first under Mathematica 9. That package had somehow problems with the SerialReadyQ function, so it wasn't really usable - but does allow the 230k comm! Then under 10.3 the newly integrated DeviceRead capability with a working DeviceExecute[ser, "SerialReadyQ"] function allowed robust communication but doesn't allow for the 230.4k... So I think I will have to write my own program for both Lin&Win. Anyways - thank you all!